# Pass data from UICollectionViewCell to another UICollectionViewCell in code without storyboards using Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, viewcontroller, pass-data

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` (say `UICollectionViewCell 1`)  that has a button and `UITextfields` inside the cell. The `UICollectionViewCell` that is connected to (`ViewController 1`) pushes `ViewController 1` to a `detailedCollectionViewCell` which is (`ViewController 2`), which also holds a button and `UITextfields` inside the cell.

This is done thru protocol and delegate. My issue, I would like to pass the data from the `UITextfields` that sits in the `UICollectionViewCell`  (`ViewController 1`) to the `detailedViewCell UITextfield` (`ViewController 2`) when hitting the button in the first `UICollectionViewCell`  (`viewController 1`).

Here is my code:

```
//Protocol View Controller 1

protocol InfoCellDelegate: class {
   func buttonToDetailCell()
}

// Inside ViewController 1 class

func buttonToDetailCell() {
    let vc = InfoViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

// UICollectionViewCell 

weak var delegate: InfoCellDelegate?

@objc func InfoButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if cellOne.text != "" {
         delegate?.buttonToDetailCell()
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a custom delegate protocol, you have control over what arguments can be passed to the function.

```
protocol InfoCellDelegate: class {
    func buttonToDetailCell(text: String?)
}

delegate?.buttonToDetailCell(text: textField.text)
```

Having said that, I think a cleaner solution is to not use a button, and catch the collection view selection event directly with `collectionView(_:, didSelectItemAt:)`.
Then you can retrieve the value from the cell.

```
// in VC1
collectionView.delegate = self

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCell
    let text = cell?.textField.text
    // do something with text
}
```

Edit:
Here's some semi-complete pseudocode that will do something like what you're after.

```
protocol ButtonDelegate: class {
    func buttonTapped(text: String?)
}

class ViewControllerOne: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, ButtonDelegate {
    func buttonTapped(text: String?) {
        let vc = ViewControllerTwo(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        vc.text = text
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: MyCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell... // etc.
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}

class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController {
    var text: String?
}

class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var button = UIButton()
    var textField = UITextField()
    weak var delegate: ButtonDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @objc private func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.buttonTapped(text: self.textField.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Samah for getting back to me, I really appreciate it! I am trying to add the code you suggested, but it's not working. I could be doing something wrong. I can't get the data to pass to the 2nd controller.

Comment: Added a code snippet, copy/paste and fill in the blanks if you like.  I would still recommend using `collectionView(_:, didSelectItemAt:)` instead of a button, but I'm guessing it's up to your designers. :)